# How to increase DPI for VLC media player in Cinnamon on UHD display?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, gui, vlc, high-dpi

My **laptop display** has **[HiDPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density#Named_pixel_densities)**, <sup>(282.42 PPI eXtra High density [according to calculator](https://www.sven.de/dpi/))</sup>, is of size **15.6** inches with resolution **3840 x 2160** and scaling set on **Double** (200%) DPI in my **[Linux Mint 19.2 "Tina" - Cinnamon (64-bit)](https://linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=267)** general settings:

---

[image: Double DPI in Cinnamon Settings - General]

---

#### [VLC media player](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html) - DPI problem

[image: VLC - default DPI]

---

I would like to change the DPI setting for it, say to 250%. But can't find any GUI scaling setting in its Preferences menu.

It has been installed via `snap`, as of this moment it's in version:

```
$ snap list vlc

Name  Version  Rev   Tracking  Publisher  Notes
vlc   3.0.7    1049  stable    videolan✓  -
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### [QT documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html#high-dpi-support-in-qt)

---

In the [QT documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html#high-dpi-support-in-qt), I have found these QT settings can be set either dynamically per application, or when [`export`](https://ss64.com/bash/export.html)ed, then I think would have a global effect on every QT application:

```
QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR
QT_SCALE_FACTOR
QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS
```

Quoting the documentation:

> `QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR` [`boolean`] enables automatic scaling, based on the monitor's pixel density. This won't change the size of point-sized fonts, since point is a physical measurement unit. Multiple screens may get different scale factors.
>
> `QT_SCALE_FACTOR` [`numeric`] defines a global scale factor for the whole application, including point-sized fonts.
>
> `QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS` [`list`] specifies scale factors for each screen. This won't change the size of point-sized fonts. The environment variable is mainly useful for debugging, or to work around monitors with wrong `EDID` information (Extended Display Identification Data).

---

#### My need

---

In my case I tried various settings to the satisfying result of:

```
QT_SCALE_FACTOR=2.5
```

From terminal (for debugging purposes) it can be run as normal user this way:

```
$ QT_SCALE_FACTOR=2.5 vlc
```

---

#### [VLC media player](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html) - DPI solved

---

[image: VLC - 250% DPI]

---

#### What I actually did

---

I don't want to make this change applied system-wide, so what I did was:

1. Copied VLC menu item onto my desktop with right click -> Add to desktop.
2. Edited the `.desktop` file's `Exec` entry to:

   ```
    Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/vlc_vlc.desktop QT_SCALE_FACTOR=2.5 /snap/bin/vlc %U
   ```

Comment: Wouldn't this make all icons and fonts blurry?

Comment: @Vanuan Not at all. Crystal crisp on UltraHD screen. I do not use VLC anymore, I uninstalled it in favor of Celluloid, which does not suffer from this. So, I can't deliver more info than I did in this answer. Cheers.